# Como fazer um load bar dentro de um load() Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Eu possuo uma página php *index.php* que de cara carrega uma outra página php *pagina.php* com um load():

```
$("#div").load('pagina.php');
```

Nessa página eu tenho um loop For com um sql demorado e tenho que mostrar o progresso dessa consulta. O problema é que essa página só é carregada na div após o fim da consulta.

Existe uma maneira de eu trazer um load com o progresso do Banco de Dados da página *pagina.php* pra dentro desse javascript que carrega antes na página *index.php* ? 
Por exemplo:

```
$('#div').html("Carregando...");
$("#div").load('pagina.php');
```

Mas em vez da mensagem "Carregando", eu preciso mostrar um progresso.

Obrigado.

Comment: Com progresso você fala de 0% até 100%?

Comment: Ele pode ser de 0% a 100% ou repartido. Só preciso de uma estimativa de que a página está tendo um progresso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<html>
<style>
div#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin: 0;">
<div id="loading">
 <div style="background:url('http://loading.io/assets/img/default-loader.gif') no-repeat center center;width:50px;height:50px;display: table-cell;"></div>
</div>
<!--

COLOCA AQUI O CORPO DA PAGINA

-->
<script>$(document).ready(function() { $('div#loading').fadeOut() });</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Você pode mudar estilo de carregadro e entre um site http://loading.io

Comment: Muito bom, eu usaria o PAC MAN de Loading.

Comment: coloquei o código para você. ate mais